# How to connect both Android and Iphone application to the same app in Facebook?

Tags: iphone, android, facebook

I have used Facebook API to make posts to my wall on Facebook with my Android app. To do this I made an app on the Facebook developer site. I used the key hash from the Android application and the APP_ID from the facebook app to cross match them.

Now I want to connect my Android app to a facebook app which already is connected to an Iphone application. This app has my key hash added, and I tried using its APP_ID instead of my own but it doesn't work.

I am thinking it might be because I'm not using the application secret in my Android app, but it is used in the Iphone app. If this could be the problem, where do I add this application secret? Xcode has such an easy system for adding parameters like this one, but I don't know what the equivalent in Android is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Facebook Android SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) instructions "make sure that your application has been signed with the same key you registered with Facebook" it sounds like you have a key mismatch issue; the instructions on their site should help find some common problems. Also update your local code to use the latest SDK as Facebook is notorious for breaking older implementations.

The current [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) only uses the application ID and Android is no different.

Comment: Then I leave the "secret key" theory and focus on getting the cross matching right. Thanks for your time!